# XA Transactions Support for Coherence*Extend clients

Tags: transactions, oracle-coherence, xa

I would like to wrap my Coherence cache update calls into transactions using the [Coherence Resource Adapter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15357_01/coh.360/e15723/api_transactionslocks.htm#COHDG5332) to have full XA support. But it seems this feature is not applicable to Coherence*Extend clients.

Is it any workaround to have Extend clients' calls to be a part of global application transactions?